# BizTalk - create log file for pipeline fault (There was a failure executing the receive pipeline)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2020

Starting with this version, BizTalk can route fault messages, and that's pretty good. Let's say I'm receiving a badly-formatted positional txt file and a receive pipeline can't let the message get into the orchestration. I can see that between the 'Suspended Services Instances' I have my suspended service gone in error with its code and its pretty explicit description.

I would love to get all this data into a file (txt) and route it into a dedicate folder, without using custom pipeline components or other libraries, just BizTalk out of the box functionalities.

Is it all possible (to save exception in log file)?

[image]

It is My File BizTalk Orchestration.(Please let me know if anything need to change).

[image]
Also, if you provide any example of it will helpful as i am beginner in **BizTalk**.

Comment: Which version of BIzTalk are you using?  No need to tag with all of the versions.

Comment: hello @Djkgraaf I have used Biztalk 2020 Can you please provide a solution beacuse we are not able to install ESB Exception Management Tools.

Comment: That sort of puts it outside the scope of Stackoverflow, as that is a project, not a simple Q&A.  At my work we did that, we created a BizTalk 2010 solution with four Orchestrations, pipelines, pipeline components, business rules, XSLT template for creating an email.  Later on we upgraded it for each version of BizTalk.

Comment: If you want a pre-written solution, you might want to look at BizTalk360  https://www.biztalk360.com/blog/biztalk-esb-exception-handling-portal-in-biztalk360/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You need some custom components or the ESB Toolkit.

If you switched on routing for failed message on the Receive Port, you can create a send port which has the Filter `ErrorReport.FailureCode Exists`  and all failed messages will go to this port. You can add additional filters to limit it to certain ports or other context properties.
The below example shows what it looks like.  It also has an additional filter as this is the [ESB Exception Management Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/using-esb-exception-management) Send Port, which is part of the ESB Toolkit.  However just adding that filter will just send the original message, without all the error information.  The Microsoft sample ESB Exception Management Framework includes a [ESB Fault Processor Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/the-esb-fault-processor-pipeline) component to get the original message and error report, and to insert them into a DB.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello @djkgraaf - can you please help me to resolved this issue is will( link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975136/edi-file-header-is-not-convert-into-xml-using-biztalk)

Comment: @Hardik I haven't done EDIFACT for quite a while, so can't help you there.