# Edi File Header is not convert into XML Using BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

I have create BizTalk project that convert EDI into XML.

It will convert all the transaction segment into XML but the Header segment n (eg. ISA) is not convert into XML format.

Here is configuration in BizTalk for EDI file.
[image]

I have not creating any mapping yet now I need only convert Header into XML now.

[image].

[image]

Let me know if anyone need more details.

Note : There is no issue if it will generate separate XML file with segment but I need only Header XML for EDI file.

Here is my Payload for EDI file:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *16*SENDER1        *ZZ*RECEIVER1      *071216*1406*U*00204*000000263*1*T*>~
GS*IN*SENDER1*RECEIVER1*20071216*1406*000000001*X*004010~
ST*850*0001~
BEG*00*SA*XX-1234**20170301**NA~
PER*BD*ED SMITH*TE*8001234567~
TAX*53247765*SP*CA*********9~
N1*BY*ABC AEROSPACE*9*1234567890101~
N2*AIRCRAFT DIVISION~
N3*2000 JET BLVD~
N4*FIGHTER TOWN*CA*98898~
PO1*1*25*EA*36*PE*MG*XYZ-1234~
MEA*WT*WT*10*OZ~
IT8*******B0~
SCH*25*EA***106*20170615~
CTT*1~
AMT*TT*900~
SE*15*0001~
GE*1*000000001~
IEA*1*000000263~
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your EDIFACT payload as text, that will make it easier for others to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I have added my payload for EDI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After The lots of Serach i have found the Code to get ISA header segment in File.

Here is my Solution:

[image]

- It will Use for the ISA_segment and GS_Segment as Well.

[image]

- So i am Resolved My Issue.